# How do I capture rails form id in jQUery

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

The below is my form which is getting generated. Before my submit action is performed, I need to something in jQuery.

```
<%form_for @user, :url => {action => "update", :id => @user.id} do |f| %>

<% end %>
```

I looked at the chrome inspect and I see everytime I get a different id for the form `"edit_user_9"`. **How do I capture the form id in jQuery**.

```
$('#edit_user_<%= @user.id %>').submit(function(){
    // for some strange reasons this is not getting fired before the rails form submit.
})
```

Comment: you want to use same id for all?

Comment: @RSB: Its about id, but why is the form getting submitted even before the jQuery call?.

Comment: Is the javascript code inside document.ready?

Comment: you need id for selector right? check my answer

Comment: Do you have your JS inside your _view.html.erb, or in an excluded js-file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it this way

```
<%= form_for @user, :url => {action => "update"}, :html => {:id => "your_custom_id"} do |f| %>
```

Comment: Its working. Thanks. putting return false in the jQUery submit will make the form not to submit right? as of now it goes into jQuery but still triggers the rails form submit too.

Answer (score 2):

You could just do with:

```
$('#edit_user_<%= @user.id %>')
```

Comment: @Shane Your question is how to get the form but not why it's not fired. Where did you put the js code?

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
$(function() {
  $('#edit_user_<%= @user.id %>').submit(function(){

  })
})
```

Comment: No, For event binding(submit event in this case) to work properly, it should be called inside document.ready. My answer is a shorthand for that.